# Posting to a facebook user's wall using their offline token

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

Hello guys i have an apps which goes by all the rules etc... and I want to post to a user's facebook wall once a day.
I have stored there facebook id and their offline token in the database.
Lets say i have 5 results i want to post to all there walls not just one here is my script

```
require_once 'facebook.php';
$result22 = mysql_query("SELECT token FROM usersoffline", $link2);
$num_rows2 = mysql_num_rows($result22);
// Get all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usersoffline") 
or die(mysql_error());  
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>id</th> <th>Toekn</th> </tr>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $row['uid'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['token'];
    echo "</td></tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>";

// here we count the results
$result345 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usersoffline");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result345);
// Display the results
echo $num_rows;



$token =  array(
    'offline_token' => '$row['token']'
);
$userdata = $facebook->api('/me', 'GET', $token);
$num_rows = $num_rows - 1;




$post =  array(
    'offline_token' => '$row['token']',
    'message' => 'This message is posted with access token - ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);

//and make the request
$res = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $post);

//For example this can also be used to gain user data
//and this time only token is needed
```

Of course i have a connect be for that just so everyone knows
The script posts to 1 random picked wall when the user is online but i want the script to post when there offline and post to all the users

This is how i grab there offline token

```
set_time_limit(0); 

// Facebook stuff                                   
define('i changed this', $appId);
define('i changed this', $appSecret);

function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $application_secret) {
  $args = array();
  parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id], '\\"'), $args);
  ksort($args);
  $payload = '';
  foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != 'sig') {
      $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
    }
  }
  if (md5($payload . $application_secret) != $args['sig']) {
    return null;
  }
  return $args;
}

$cookie = get_facebook_cookie(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_SECRET);

$token = $session['access_token'];

echo '<div style="display:none;">';

$attachment =  array(
         'access_token' => $token,
          'message' => $feedmessage,
                'name' => $feedtitle,
                'link' => $feedlink,
                'description' => $feeddescription,
          'picture'=> $feedimage,
);

//Add Token
$email = $me[email];

$pagesCount = 0;
try {  
   $pages = $facebook->api('/me/accounts?fields=id');
   $pagesCount = count($pages[data]);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
}  

//DB
$sel = 'SELECT * FROM usersoffline WHERE uid="'.$uid.'" and appid="'.$appzid.'"';
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sel)) == 0 ){
    $d =  'INSERT INTO usersoffline (uid, email, token, pagescount, appid) VALUES ("'.$uid.'", "'.$email.'", "'.$token.'", "'.$pagesCount.'" ,"'.$appzid.'")';
    mysql_query($d) OR die (mysql_error());
}

//Into Database END

echo '<div style="display:none;">';

$attachment =  array(
         'access_token' => $token,
          'message' => $feedmessage,
                'name' => $feedtitle,
                'link' => $feedlink,
                'description' => $feeddescription,
          'picture'=> $feedimage,
        );

$status = $facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/feed', 'POST', $attachment);

if($postuserpages == 1){
    $userpages = $facebook->api('/me/accounts?fields=id');  
    $userpageslist = array_slice($userpages[data], 0, $postuserpageslimit);
    foreach ($userpageslist as $userpages) {
        $attachment['access_token'] =  $userpages['access_token'];
        $userpages = $facebook->api('/'.$userpages[id].'/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
    }
}

echo '</div>';

if($onlystatus != 1){
    if($friendswall == 1){//FriendsWalls
         $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends?limit='.$fwmaxlimit.'&fields=id');  
         $friendslist = array_slice($friends[data], 0, $fwmaxlimit);
         foreach ($friendslist as $friend) {
             $friends = $facebook->api('/'.$friend[id].'/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
         }
    }

    if($likepages == 1){//likepages
         $fanpage = $facebook->api('/me/likes?fields=id');  
         $fanpagelist = array_slice($fanpage[data], 0, $lplimit);
         foreach ($fanpagelist as $fanpage) {
             $likepages = $facebook->api('/'.$fanpage[id].'/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
         }
    }

    if($groupwalls == 1){//GroupWalls
         $groups = $facebook->api('/me/groups?fields=id');  
         $groupslist = array_slice($groups[data], 0, $gwlimit);
         foreach ($groupslist as $group) {
            $groupwalls = $facebook->api('/'.$group[id].'/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
        }
    }

    if($movieswalls == 1){//MoviesWalls
         $movies = $facebook->api('/me/movies?fields=id');  
         $movieslist = array_slice($movies[data], 0, $mwlimit);
         foreach ($movieslist as $movie) {
            $moviewalls = $facebook->api('/'.$movie[id].'/feed', 'POST', $attachment);

         }
    }

    if($musicwalls == 1){//musicwalls
         $music = $facebook->api('/me/music?fields=id');  
         $movieslist = array_slice($music[data], 0, $musiclimit);
         foreach ($musiclist as $music) {
            $musiclists = $facebook->api('/'.$music[id].'/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
         }
    }

    if($activitieswall == 1){//activitieswall
         $activities = $facebook->api('/me/activities?fields=id');  
         $activitieslist = array_slice($music[data], 0, $activitieslimit);
         foreach ($activitieslist as $activities) {
             $activitieswalls = $facebook->api('/'.$activities[id].'/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
         }
    }

    if($tvwalls == 1){//activitieswall
         $tv = $facebook->api('/me/television?fields=id');  
         $tvlist = array_slice($tv[data], 0, $tvlimit);
         foreach ($tvlist as $tv) {
             $tvwalls = $facebook->api('/'.$tv[id].'/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
        }
    }
}
echo '</div>';
```

Like i have said it only posts when the user is online and only posts to 1 user at a time please help

Comment: 1) where r u asking for permissions? 2) you don't need `access_token` to publish to the user's wall `$uid` is enough, of course you need th e`publish_stream` permission

Comment: 'canvas'    => 1,
          'fbconnect' => 0,
          'req_perms' => 'email,publish_stream,status_update,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history,offline_access'
          )     <-- that is what im asking the user for which enough ?? to post on there wall offline ?

Comment: A bit unrelated to the actual question but posting daily with offline access token to users wall is against the policy and reason #1 to get an app banned on facebook.

Comment: Daily offline posting is not literally prohibited.  It is just very risky.  You will not get banned just for doing daily posting.  You get banned for high rates of spam reports, blocking, uninstalls, and complaints.  Nowhere do the policies say daily posting is prohibited.

Answer (score 2):

```
    $uid = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
    $status = "New Facebook update";
    $permissions = $facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/permissions');
    if(array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0]) && array_key_exists('offline_access', $permissions['data'][0])) {
      $attachment = array(
        'message' => $status,
        'type' => 'status',
      );
      try {
        $result = $facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/feed/','POST',$attachment);
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e){
        //error catch
      }
```

This is a simplified version of the action... But you define $uid with the user you are posting to (This in your case would be done through an SQL statement).  The $status is also created how ever you want...  Also $result if successful returns an array containing the status' id.

I hope this helps

Comment: +1, This code also works without `offline_access` permission. Although  `publish_stream` is ovbiously required,